# VS Code Intelephense wrong path completion in html

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I'm using Intelephense for code completion in VS Code. Works pretty good. But path completion isn't working correct. When I try to get the path to a picture it shows me the wrong picture selection.

Like this:`<img src="./images/picture.jpg">`

But it should look like this:`<img src="./images/myPicture.jpg">`

It looks like it goes down the tree one folder.

```
|   
|--myFolder <Workspace>  
|  |--images  
|  |  \--myPicture.jpg
|  | 
|  \--index.php
|
|--images
|  \--picture.jpg <wrong picture>
|
|--index.php
```

I renamed the index.php in myFolder then I used `${workspaceFolder}` in Document Root but nothing chanced! And I couldn't find anything on the net about that problem.

Is there anyone who knows about that? It's really annoying.

Comment: try to upgrade your vs code and use latest version of intelephense too

Comment: @AdamStrauss both are at the latest version